# How to reload dropdown options in Jtable with Jquery

Tags: jquery-jtable

Can anyone please tell me how can I refresh/reload the drop-down options while in Add/Edit mode.

I wanted to add a refresh/reload icon by the drop-down, so I can refresh the drop-down options. I googled but didn't get any idea on this.

Need your help guys :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For optimization purpose jTable `caches` all option lists based on URL, and gets options from local cache if you return exactly same URL,
Use `data.clearCache()` function- This method is used to clear cache for currently returning URL. So, you can ensure that your options will be re-downloaded. It is well documented [Here](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions).
Use following code for reference

```
PhoneType: {
    title: 'Phone type',
    options: function(data) {
        data.clearCache();  // Use this to clear cache
        if (data.source == 'list') {

            return '/Demo/GetPhoneTypes.php?UserType=0';
        }
        //data.source == 'edit' || data.source == 'create'
        return '/Demo/GetPhoneTypes.php?UserType=' + data.record.UserType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi abpatil, 

Thanks for the reply, but my requirement is something custom. Like if I take reference of your sample code. 

Suppose there is one more option "Add New" in the "Phone Types" dropdown and when I choose "Add New", this opens a second popup for adding a new "Phone Type". Now on successful addition of "Phone Type", the "Phone Type" popup will disappear. and the new added "Phone Type" should appear in the "Phone Type" dropdown.

i.e. making an entry in child popup should reload the options in parent popup.

Hope this makes sence.